# Scrape Web Pages with Beautiful Soup and Python 3

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Started learning python 3 and beautiful soap 
trying to get the result from a web page with the following code:

```
import mechanicalsoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open("http://www.intellicast.com/")
browser.select_form()
browser["query"] = input("Enter city,Country")
response = browser.submit_selected()
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
right_table = soup.find_all('td', id="conditions")
print(right_table)
```

I'm stuck at this point
Based on user input result should look like this:

32°F
Feels Like: 23°
Wind Chill: 23°
Ceiling:    5400
Heat Index: 32°
Visibility: 10mi
Dew Point:  16°
Wind:       12mph
Humidity:   51%
Direction:  330°NNW
Pressure:   30.53"
Gusts:      17mph

How to get this result, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which user input values are producing the above please?

Comment: Took random inputs Ex- Toronto,Canada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove comment from the html which are `<!--[if lte IE 9]>` and `<![endif]-->`  and `.select()` right element

```
...
html = response.text
html = html.replace('<!--[if lte IE 9]>', '').replace('<![endif]-->', '')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
right_table = soup.select('#conditions tr')
for tr in right_table:
    print(tr.text.replace('\n', ''))
```

Comment: Nice answer.. Do you stay on SO all the time?

Comment: I'm trying to get 10 day weather forecast from same website after user inputs. I'm unable scrape html. Please help.